# Replace column values with their frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to replace values in a Pandas column with their respective frequencies in the column.

I'm aware I can use `value_counts` to retrieve the frequency distribution for each value in the column. What I'm not sure on is how to replace every occurance of a value with its respective frequency.

An example dataframe:

```
   a      b  c
0  tiger  2  3
1  tiger  5  6
2  lion   8  9
```

Example output of `df['a'].value_counts()`:

```
tiger    2
lion     1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Expected result when applied to column 'a':

```
   a  b  c
0  2  2  3
1  2  5  6
2  1  8  9
```

Comment: try ```df.a = df.a.map(df.a.value_counts())```

Comment: @McGuile - One possible solution is use `replace` instead `map` for more columns

Comment: @jezrael Any benefit to `replace` vs a loop over desired columns with `map`?

Comment: replace is used for multiple columns, if want map it working only with one column/Series so necessary `apply(lambda x: x.map(df.a.value_counts()))`. But map is faster, only NaNs if no match